# Select Query and Update Query in same StoredProcedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, system.data

I have a stored procedure in which I'll select some rows based on a condition and I need to update the status of those rows within the same stored procedure.
For e.g.

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[myProcedure]
As
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN T1
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT TOP 5 * INTO #TempTable FROM myTable WHERE ENABLED = 1;
UPDATE myTable SET [Status] = 'Locked' From myTable Inner Join on #TempTable myTable.id = #TempTable.id;
SELECT * FROM #TempTable;
DROP Table #TempTable;
COMMIT TRAN T1
END
```

The Stored Procedure works fine when I debug in SQL. I'm accessing the StoredProcedure through C# like this.

```
private ProcessData[] ReadFromDb(string StoredProcedure, SqlConnection Connection)
        {
            List<ProcessData> Data = new List<ProcessData>();
            SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedure, Connection);
            Command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            try
            {
                Command.CommandTimeout = CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;
                using (SqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (Reader.Read())
                    {
                        Data.Add(new ProcessData()
                        {
                              Id = Reader["Id"];
                              ...
                           });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {}
        }
```

The problem is I'm getting the required rows in C# but the update query in stored procedure is not working.
Can anyone give some suggestions where I'm going wrong.

Comment: is **"From myTable Inner Join myTable.id = #TempTable.id;"** your real code

Comment: You are ignoring the exception in `catch (Exception ex){}`. If `COMMIT TRAN T1` fails for any reason, you'll get the rows, but updates will be rolled back. I suspect this is what's happening.

Comment: I'm handling the exception in real code, but I'm not getting any exception. In code I'm getting the selected rows. Update query not updating the value. If I debug stored procedure in SQL update query is working fine

Answer (score 1):

The following line of procedure

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET [Status] = 'Locked' 
From myTable 
Inner Join myTable.id = #TempTable.id;
```

should be

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET [Status] = 'Locked' 
From myTable 
Inner Join #TempTable 
   on myTable.id = #TempTable.id;
```

And `COMMINT TRAN T1` should be replaced by `COMMIT TRAN T1`

And finally, you should not use `SELECT TOP` without `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT TOP 5 * INTO #TempTable FROM myTable WHERE ENABLED = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine

UPDATE
    A
SET
    foo = B.bar
FROM
    TableA A
    JOIN
    TableB B ON A.col1 = B.colx
WHERE
    ...

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET [Status] = 'Locked'  
From myTable  
WHERE id in (select TOP 5 * FROM myTable WHERE enabled=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OUTPUT clause to do this in one statement without creating a temp table.

Refer to [this post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-output-clause-example-and-explanation-with-insert-update-delete/) for examples.